# Where are php's extensions .so files located?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, php-ini, .so

I opened some some ini files like **mysqli.ini** , **mysql.ini** ,  **pdo_mysql.ini**. Inside those files there is an .so extension added for those files. I want to know where these **.so** files are stored.

Inside mysqli.ini file

```
; configuration for php MySQL module
; priority=20
extension=mysqli.so
```

Inside mysql.ini file

```
; configuration for php MySQL module
; priority=20
extension=mysql.so
```

Inside pdo_mysql.ini file

```
; configuration for php MySQL module
; priority=20
extension=pdo_mysql.so
```

Comment: `locate mysql.so`

Comment: I'm using unix system and it says zsh: command not found: locate

Comment: Then try `whereis mysql.so`

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The .so files should be located inside your php extension directory.

You can use phpinfo() function to find the location of your php extension directory or you can use php -i from the command line.

Example

```
root@73fa7795de48:/# php -i | grep extension_dir
extension_dir => /usr/lib/php/20160303 => /usr/lib/php/20160303
```

Comment: this is not always correct, it highly depends on the linux distro. in my (Alpine) there is no such a folder `/usr/lib/php/`

Answer (score 7):

On Linux system

```
php -i | grep extension_dir  | cut -d " " -f 5
```

will display you the current php extension dir